# Compute telescopic sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

Is there a nice or simple form for a sum of the following form? 
$$ 1 + \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n-1+i}{i} - \binom{n-1+i}{i-1}$$

Motivation: Due to a computation in the formalism of Schubert calculus the above sum with $k = \lceil n/2 \rceil -1$  is equal to the number of lines intersecting $2n-4$ general subspaces $H_j\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $n-2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a power tool when a manual tool does the trick.

Hockey-stick identity:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n+i}{i} = \binom{n+k+1}{k}
$$

Applying to our expression:

$$
1 + \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n-1+i}{i} - \binom{n-1+i}{i-1} \\
1 + \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n-1+i}{i} - \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n-1+i}{i-1} \\
1 - \binom{n-1}{0} + \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n-1+i}{i} - \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n+i}{i} \\
\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n-1+i}{i} - \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n+i}{i} \\
\binom{n+k}{k} - \binom{n+k+1}{k} \\
\binom{n+k}{k} - \left(\binom{n+k}{k-1}+\binom{n+k}{k}\right) \\
-\binom{n+k}{k-1}
$$

Comment: Do you have a reference to the particular form of the Hockey-stick identity you are using? I can only find it with a constant 'denominator' for the binomials involved.

Comment: Apply the symmetric identity for each term: $\binom{n+i}{i} = \binom{n+i}{n}$

Comment: Is anyone going to explain why it's called the Hockey-stick identity??

Comment: Its name is derived from the shape the binomial coefficients form when you plot them on Pascal's triangle. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383141/notation-for-nested-sums-of-arbitrary-degree/3383165#3383165

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

The following method does not use telescopic series but it makes use of elementary binomial theorem along with some geometric progression to arrive at the answer.

$$\begin{aligned}S&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}{n-1+i\choose n-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{k}{n-1+i\choose n}\\&=\left(\text{coeff. of } x^{n-1} \text{ in } \sum_{i=1}^{k}(1+x)^{n-1+i}\right)-\left(\text{coeff. of } x^{n} \text{ in } \sum_{i=1}^{k}(1+x)^{n-1+i}\right)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Is there some reason why the sum on the right-hand-side of your first line is equal to mine? Although they look similar at first sight the 'denominator' of the binomial is constant in yours while it varies in mine?

Comment: @A.VanWerde I have used the property of binomial coefficients $${n\choose r}={n\choose n-r}$$.